# Filter Layered Navigation: Specify Filter for Subcategory

Tags: category, layered-navigation, filtered-nav

I set up a category-based navigation on our central shop page and added some filters. I also added some subcategories to the main-shop category, in order to make the products more accessible. 
My Problem now is: there does not seem to be a way of adding filters to certain sub-categories.

**Example:**
Let's say you clicked on my category page "Sports" (subcategory), you maybe want to filter ingredients (like vitamins, magnesium...). So I want to add an attribute-based filter to the sub-category-page - named "ingredients" - that makes it easier for you to filter the magnesium-based products on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

https://store.plumrocket.com/product-filter-magento-extension.html

Be advised: google is very likely to index your result pages.

When you use different filters for categories (lets say "tools") and subcategories ("hammers), google will index a "tools page" and a "hammer page".

As a result you will end up with a huge amount of indexed pages.

Make sure you set noindex, and a proper canonical on your result pages.